# Is a rockbreaker a vehicle?

Tags: word-usage

Here are some definitions about "vehicle".

> [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle): A vehicle is a machine that transports people or cargo.
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vehicle): a machine, usually with wheels and an engine, used for transporting people or goods on land, especially on roads

Obviously, bicycles, cars, buses and trucks are vehicles.

How about this one, designed to break large rocks into smaller ones. I am aware that it could be called a machine.

[image]

It is not used for transporting people or goods. Should I still call it vehicle?

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: These types of machines are usually referred to as "heavy equipment" or "heavy machinery." However, it is accurate to refer to them as "vehicles" if they are capable of being driven around under their own power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, it's a piece of heavy equipment, and it has tracks, not wheels. It is mobile in the sense of moving around at a job site, but it would be moved to the job site on an actual wheeled trailer.
As a moving device, it doesn't transport anything but itself or its operator, so it would not usually be called a vehicle.